# Набор элементов each() и сравнение по индексу

Tags: jquery, index, javascript

Всем привет.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("p.more-name").each(function(indx){
          $( this ).addClass( "foo" );
          alert( index);
});
</script>
```

Класс добавляет. Как получить индекс, подскажите, пожалуйста?  )

Comment: В вашем примере есть опечатка:

1) function(indx)

2) alert(index);

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить класс ко всем нужным элементам, необязательно использовать `each`, при ваших условиях `each` вообще не нужно. Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/evgtn9o0/1/).

Comment: Добавление класса как проверка, что перебирает элементы в целом) Спасибо, что нашли опечатку)

Answer (score 1):

Выше человек сказал все правильно, я лишь добавлю. Если в JQuery нужно получить индекс элемента, то рабочее слово не "index" а "eq". И в коде это выглядело бы примерно так.

```
$("p.more-name").each(function(indx){
          $( this ).addClass( "foo" );
          alert($( this ).eq());
});
```

Если я не ошибаюсь, давненько на JQuery не писал.
Ну и это лично ваш случай. А вообще да, этот цикл здесь ни к чему.